# Having nullable foreign keys in one-to-one relationship with more than one entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I wanted Movie, Actor, Director, User etc entities to have exactly one Image and an Image to belong to exactly one entity. I defined and configured them as -

**Models :** (simplified)

```cs
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

// Director, User etc are defined in similar way

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Base64 { get; set; }

    public int? MovieId { get; set; }
    public int? ActorId { get; set; }
    public int? DirectorId { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; } 
}
```

**Configurations :** (simplified)

```cs
public class MovieConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Movie>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Movie> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Movie");
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Property(p => p.Title).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("nvarchar(128)");
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Image)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Image>(e => e.MovieId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

// Actors, Director, User etc are configured in similar way

public class ImageConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Image>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Image> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Image");
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Property(p => p.Base64).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");
    }
}
```

This generates the schema with Image table having one-to-one relationship with each of Movie, Actor, Director, User etc table, as expected.

What's bothering me are all those `nullable` foreign-key fields in Image, because -

1. a new `nullable` foreign-key must be added whenever a new entity with Image is introduced
2. for any image entry only one of those foreign-key columns is going to have a value

What other ways I could define and configure the entities to achieve the same result while avoiding those `nullable` foreign-keys?

**Edit :**
Or is it, in general practice, considered OK to have a schema like the one I currently have (with multiple `nullable` foreign-keys where only one of them can have a value)?

I don't have a lot of experience in database design/schema and best/general practices. It just felt wrong to me and that's where the question came.

So, please feel free to give your opinion and suggestion?

Comment: There are many approaches (and questions & answers) for these *polymorphic associations*. Multiple FKs is certainly not the worst one.

Answer (score -1):

Create relationship for MovieId, ActorId, DirectorId and UserId in Image table in sql server.

Then re-update your dbcontext and those foreign IDs will be auto saved from movie, actor, director and user when inserting.

Comment: The relationships you are talking about will be created automatically when I generate the schema. Why do I have to create them explicitly in SQL Server? I'm not sure if you understood the question.

Comment: if your relationships are created already, you won't have nullable foreign key fields already as their fields will be saved automatically. so you need to check your relationships.